# Big Ω time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have this code which signifies a greedy algorithm. It adds programs from nums[] until there is no space left on diskSize. It's assumed that nums[] is sorted in order of ascending value and that the total sum of nums[] is > diskSize.

```
public static int maxPrograms(int[] nums, int diskSize) {
        int numPrograms = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length && nums[i] <= diskSize; i++) {
            diskSize -= nums[i];
            numPrograms++;
        }

        return numPrograms;
    }
```

I believe that the time complexity would be O(n), with a maximum of O(n - 1) iterations in the worst case. What I'm unsure of is the Ω time complexity, which I believe would be Ω(1).

I think it's Ω because in the best case scenario, all items in nums[] are larger than diskSize, and the loop is never triggered. Would this be correct, or am I misjudging this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248686/discussion-on-question-by-tydal-big--time-complexity-of-this-algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

As long as nums[0] is less than or equal to diskSize, the loop will never be triggered, giving you Ω(1).

for example, heres the algorithm reimplemented in JavaScript:

```js
function maxPrograms(nums, diskSize) {
  let numPrograms = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < nums.length && nums[i] <= diskSize; i++) {
    console.log("Loop Trigerred")
    diskSize -= nums[i];
    numPrograms++;
  }

  return numPrograms;
}

console.log(maxPrograms(5, [4]))
```

Comment: For clarity's sake, you mean as long as nums[0] is greater than diskSize, right?